# Unity watermark on image after screenshot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a watermark on my image, and this is the code I have for taking a screenshot. Can someone teach me how to implement watermark into my image? I want a small logo at the top right hand side of the image.

I am trying to research on maybe if I could implement what I have in the canvas to stay when a screenshot is taken ( real life ). But to no luck. Would really appreciate if someone could help me out here !

```
public string MakePhoto(bool openIt)
{          
    int resWidth = Screen.width;
    int resHeight = Screen.height;

    Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false); //Create new texture
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);        

    // hide the info-text, if any
    if (infoText) 
    {
        infoText.text = string.Empty;
    }
    // render background and foreground cameras
    if (backroundCamera && backroundCamera.enabled) 
    {
        backroundCamera.targetTexture = rt;
        backroundCamera.Render();
        backroundCamera.targetTexture = null;
    }

    if (backroundCamera2 && backroundCamera2.enabled) 
    {
        backroundCamera2.targetTexture = rt;
        backroundCamera2.Render();
        backroundCamera2.targetTexture = null;
    }

    if (foreroundCamera && foreroundCamera.enabled) 
    {
        foreroundCamera.targetTexture = rt;
        foreroundCamera.Render();
        foreroundCamera.targetTexture = null;
    }

    // get the screenshot
    RenderTexture prevActiveTex = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = rt;

    screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);

    // clean-up
    RenderTexture.active = prevActiveTex;
    Destroy(rt);

    byte[] btScreenShot = screenShot.EncodeToJPG();
    Destroy(screenShot);

    #if !UNITY_WSA
    // save the screenshot as jpeg file
    string sDirName = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Screenshots";
    if (!Directory.Exists(sDirName))
        Directory.CreateDirectory (sDirName);

    string sFileName = sDirName + "/" + string.Format ("{0:F0}", Time.realtimeSinceStartup * 10f) + ".jpg";
    File.WriteAllBytes(sFileName, btScreenShot);

    Debug.Log("Photo saved to: " + sFileName);
    if (infoText) 
    {
        infoText.text = "Saved to: " + sFileName;
    }

    // open file
    if(openIt)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sFileName);
    }

    return sFileName;
```

PS: I found this which might be useful?

```
public Texture2D AddWatermark(Texture2D background, Texture2D watermark)
{

    int startX = 0;
    int startY = background.height - watermark.height;

    for (int x = startX; x < background.width; x++)
    {

        for (int y = startY; y < background.height; y++)
        {
            Color bgColor = background.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color wmColor = watermark.GetPixel(x - startX, y - startY);

            Color final_color = Color.Lerp(bgColor, wmColor, wmColor.a / 1.0f);

            background.SetPixel(x, y, final_color);
        }
    }

    background.Apply();
    return background;
}
```

Comment: where does your whatermark come from? (Sprite? another Texture2D?)

Comment: Sprite i guess? It's just an image I have. I am still new to unity and c#. Sorry about that ( sprite (2d and ui) )

Comment: You should avoid using `SetPixel` in loops ... rather make your changes in a local `Color[]` and use `SetPixels` to change all pixels in the texture at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select the imported image in the `ProjectsView` and in the inspector set `TextureType` to `Sprite (2D and UI)` (see [Sprites Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Sprites.html)) and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>
2. add a `Sprite` field for it to your class like

   ```
   public Texture2D watermark;
   ```
3. Reference the `watermark` in the Inspector
4. You could simply add the watermark as overlay by adding the `Color` values from both textures for each pixel (**assuming here they have the same size!**)

   If you want a watermark only in a certain rect of the texture you either have to scale it accordingly and use [Texture2D.SetPixels(int x, int y, int blockWidth, int blockHeight, Color[] colors)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) (**This assumes the watermark image is smaller in pixels than the screenShot!**) like

   ```
   private static void AddWaterMark(Texture2D texture, Texture2D watermarkTexture)
   {
       int watermarkWidth = watermarkTexture.width;
       int watermarkHeight = watermarkTexture.height;

       // In Unity differrent to most expectations the pixel corrdinate
       // 0,0 is not the top-left corner but instead the bottom-left
       // so since you want the whatermark in the top-right corner do
       int startx = texture.width - watermarkWidth;  
       // optionally you could also still leave a border of e.g. 10 pixels by using
       // int startx = texture.width - watermarkWidth - 10;

       // same for the y axis
       int starty = texture.height - watermarkHeight;

       Color[] watermarkPixels = watermarkTexture.GetPixels();
       // get the texture pixels for the given rect
       Color[] originalPixels = texture.GetPixels(startx, starty, watermarkWidth, watermarkHeight);

       for(int i = 0; i < watermarkPixels.Length; i++)
       {
           var pixel = watermarkPixels[i];
           // adjust the alpha value of the whatermark
           pixel.a *= 0.5f;
           // add watermark pixel to original pixel
           originalPixels[i] += pixel;
       }

       // write back the changed texture data
       texture.SetPixels(startx, starty, watermarkWidth, watermarkHeight, originalPixels);
       texture.Apply();
   }
   ```

   call it like

   ```
   screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
   AddWaterMark(screenShot, watermark);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but how do I call it ?
texcolor = AddWhaterMark(texcolor, ?)

Comment: Ups I removed it in on of the edits ^^ here it is again

Comment: It says texture not readable, the texture memory cannot be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the texture import settings.

Comment: Color[] whatermarkPixels = whatermarkTexture.GetPixels(); the error line points to here

Comment: The original size of my picture is 200 x 200 incase it is needed

Comment: Nvm, i got it to work! But its currently at the bottom left side, how do I shift it up?

Comment: you where the one with the flipped screenshot, right? do you apply it after or before the flipping?

Comment: Oh, ok i got it on top now that I put it after the flipping

Comment: Is it able to move it to the left side? Its on the right side now

Comment: I I thought you wanted it `top right`? But sure simply replace `int startx = 0;`

Comment: Ohh, my bad for that haha. Anyways, really thanks alot. You saved my life! My presentation is in 30mins for my school project. And I managed to solve this problem thanks to you~

Comment: Ummmm, replace with that? :X

Comment: yeah use `int startx = 0;` instead of `int startx = texture.width - whatermarkWidth;` than it starts at the left side instead

Comment: Alright~ All's done! Kudos to you buddy! Helped me big time