# How to add watermark to an image in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following this solution [Unity watermark on image after screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629898/unity-watermark-on-image-after-screenshot) to add watermark to the image but it does not go forward from a line. I am using unity 2018.3.8f. If someone can help it is the matter of my job I am stuck in this for five days.

```
Color[] whatermarkPixels = whatermarkTexture.GetPixels();
```

Comment: @praveen can u help me?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried this before. I will update you if I get any useful thing to share regarding this

Comment: i am waiting thankyou

Comment: Are you just trying to overlay the image with the watermark?
And your image is a texture2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you get the same error as the OP of the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54629898/7111561), Something like

> texture not readable, the texture memory cannot be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the texture import settings

Just as it says you have to mark that texture as **readable**. Otherwise `GetPixels` fails.

For the one you have as an image file (the watermark) you can do it via the  [Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html) simply enable the `Read/Write Enabled` option and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd>

[image]

Comment: After this it runs successfuly but watermark doesnot appears on image